# Unity C#: Communicate with console program asynchronously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console-application, communication

I'm currently trying to write a **chess GUI in Unity**. I have a chess engine as an exe-file which communicates via UCI (console). The program is in a very early stage and I just want to communicate with the chess engine (console application) as a proof of concept.

At the moment I'm using the **Process class** with a redirected output and input. Everything that the chess engine outputs is currently being printed in the unity console. Unfortunately nothing I try works like expected.

**How the Chess Engine (Console Program) works:**

- User can write a command in the console e.g. "uci" or "go dept 1"
- The engine will respond with "uciok" or "bestmove e2e4"
  These responses can also have multiple lines.

**What I want:**

1. Press play in Unity
2. My script instantly sends the message "uci" to the chess engine
3. The output (muliple lines) gets printed to the unity console
4. Everytime I press 'c' step 2 and 3 get repeated

**What currently happens:**

1. Press play in Unity
2. Console (chess engine) opens
3. I manually have to close the console window
4. The message "uci" gets sent to the chess engine
5. Multiple lines get outputted to the unity console
6. When I press 'c' I'm getting an IOException

What I've also tried:

- startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; --> I have to close unity with the task manager as it waits until the process finishes
- engineProcess.WaitForExit(); --> Does not work, as the process is not supposed to exit
- engineProcess.BeginOutputReadLine(); --> I'm getting spammed by unity with exceptions because I'm mixing synchronus and asynchronous operations
- Many other solutions already suggested on StackOverflow. Nothing worked so far :(

I'm pretty new to Unity and C#, so I hope that this question does not make me look stupid. I posted my code below.

```
public string pathToExe = "PathToExe";
private Process engineProcess;

//gets automatically called once when I press start in Unity 
private void Start() {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = pathToExe;

    //Start process and write "uci" to chess engine
    try {
        engineProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
        engineProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("uci");
    }
    catch {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error when starting Engine");
    }
}

//gets called every tick when Unity is running
private void Update() {
    //write uci to chess engine when c is pressed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)) {
        engineProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("uci");
    }
    //read engine output if it exists
    while (!engineProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
        string line = engineProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would help finding a solution if you described how the interaction for every step looks if performed only using the console directly.

Comment: I added a quick description on what you can expect from the chess engine. Thanks for the tipp.

Comment: Doesnt unity use the standard process run option. If so you can turn events and it will fire events when std out and std err is sent

Comment: Your main problem is that the `while` loop in `Update` waits (synchronously, not asynchronously) until `stdout` of the chess engine closes. So the comment `//read engine output if it exists` should really be `//read engine output until it closes`

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up @Petrusion. The problem which forced me to close the console window was the result of that misunderstanding. Functionally I was able to achieve my desired result by leaving out the `while` loop and replacing `StandardOutput.ReadLine()` with `StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync()`. I will still get spammed by exceptions, that I'm already reading a line.

Comment: @Daweed Of course you are getting exceptions. You start waiting asynchronously for a line to read, then you try to start waiting for it again and again every frame. You are going to have to make sure not to start async reading the chess engine if you are already doing it. Also, I hope this chess engine sends some specific message when it is done sending it's current responses, you are going to have no way of knowing when to stop asynchronously reading lines otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BugFinder to pointing out that there are events that you can attach a method to. Using your tipps and the documentation of [Process.BeginOutputReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline?view=net-6.0) I was able to solve the problem.
I commented where I added or removed line in comparison with the original code.

```
public string pathToExe;
private Process engineProcess;

private void Start() {
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    startInfo.FileName = pathToExe;

    try {
        engineProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
        engineProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("uci");
    }
    catch {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error when starting Engine");
    }

    //Added these two lines so the method "engineOutputHandler" 
    //gets automatically called every time an output is received
    engineProcess.OutputDataReceived += engineOutputHandler;
    engineProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

private void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C)) {
        engineProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("uci");
    }

    //removed the entire while loop

}

//Added this method, which prints out the data received
private void engineOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(outLine.Data);
    }
}
```